# Images is not converting to gray scale

Tags: python, opencv, matplotlib, colormap

I have read all the images in a folder through OpenCV. Then converting to gray scale, using `pyplot` I have shown all the images. But instead of grayscale images look like yellowish.

```py
import glob
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from skimage.color import rgb2gray

images = [cv2.imread(file) for file in glob.glob(r"C:\Users\USER\Handcrafted dataset/*.jpg")]
for img in images:
    img = rgb2gray(img)
    plt.figure(figsize=(10,10))
    plt.imshow(img)
```

Sample output:

[image]

What should I do to convert them to proper grayscale images?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This happens because Matplotlib uses a colormap when plotting a single channel. In their [docs](https://matplotlib.org/3.2.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html) there are a statement saying:

> The input may either be actual RGB(A) data, or 2D scalar data, which
>   **will be rendered as a pseudocolor image**. Note: For actually displaying
>   a grayscale image set up the color mapping using the parameters
>   `cmap='gray'`, `vmin=0`, `vmax=255`.

So, change your last line to:

```
plt.imshow(img, cmap='gray')
```

This will plot the channel using the gray mapping.